# Kerberos authentication

Tags: java, jboss, cxf, jax-ws, kerberos

I have a jax-ws (cxf) client runs on jboss 7.1.
This client call a (.net) web service runs on WAS . The service require a Kerberos authentication . Both client and service run on windows (on different machines of course) and use same Active Directory domain.
I have implemented the necessary classes on my client to add the Kerberos authentication info to the port.
Is there a need in any configuration on the jboss in order to make this authentication work ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. JBoss needs to be configured, for example it needs login-module to be configured:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Configure_Kerberos_or_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Desktop_SSO_for_Web_Applications.html

Comment: thank you @greenmarker . Can you say it is two differents tasks : configure jboss to use Active directory , and configure jboss to use kerveros ?

Comment: Configuring JBoss to use Kerberos is part of configuring it to use Active Directory. You can use AD alone (just LDAP), but it's impossible to use Kerberos in AD (without LDAP, because it stores account information there).